# php SOAP response encoding issue

Tags: php, soap, encoding

all I had to do was change the default charset in my php.ini file

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

<strike>I'm trying to create a SOAP client in PHP, but I'm having trouble with encoding. The $Response has words with incorrect characters like Ã¨ instead of è.</strike>

When importing the WSDL file into [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) (a soap test suite) responses come back correctly encoded, so I don't think it has to do with the SOAP service. SoapUI indicates that it's using UTF-8. I've also tried a bunch of other [encodings](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php), but without success.

All my php files are encoded in UTF-8.

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_file, array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));
$Response = $client->__soapCall('GetMemberDetails', array($request));
debug($Response); die;
```

A sample response:

```
<members xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <UserInfo>
    ...
    <Status>rÃ¨gle</Status>
    ...
  </UserInfo>
</members>
```

This is the raw request from SoapUI

```
POST http://test.app.com/WebServices/MemberService/MemberService.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://test.org/MemberService/GetMemberDetails"
Content-Length: 419
Host: test.app.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

is there a way to get the same kind of raw request from SoapClient in PHP?

edit: I intercepted the request in __doRequest. Here are the differences between SoapClient and SoapUI

SoapClient (receives encoding errors)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://test.org/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetMemberDetails>
      <ns1:memberId>123</ns1:memberId>
    </ns1:GetMemberDetails>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

SoapUI (receives correct encoding)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://test.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetMemberDetails>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:memberId>123</tem:memberId>
      </tem:GetMemberDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure php charset is configure correctly

in your php.ini file

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```